# correct way to use .gitignore? Is it potentially dangerous?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

From my understanding .gitignore makes git ignore files that are "irrelevant" to the project, and those files are just sit there in your harddrive, won't be affected no matter how you use git.

However, recently when I'm using gitea and its gitignore templates, I've encountered this situation that seems quite dangerous:

*.dll was somehow added to .gitignore, thus when I clone my project from server to my new device, those dlls disappeared and the project become unusable. (Fortunately I still have copy on my old device)

It seems gitea's ignore templates are not 100% safe to use, but I myself can't figure out much on what files can be SAFELY ignored. Currently I have to just leave .gitignore blank.

So what's the proper way to use .gitignore?

Comment: Only you can determine what files in your project can be safely ignored. It's common to ignore .dll files and other binary files because these are typically build artifacts -- that is, they are generated by source code in the project itself. If that's not the case for your project, then you would need to change the templates.

Comment: Big ***warning***: By stating a file in .gitignore, you also mark it as *dispensible*, i.e., you give Git permission to remove the file at any time it likes. There is currently no way to instruct Git that some files should be ignored, but are also precious.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 relevant ignore files:

- `.gitignore` should ignore *all* files built by your project's normal builds, since the patterns are the same for everyone using your project (but differ between projects). This obviously includes DLLs, since built files (whether yours or your dependencies') never be committed to your repository - they belong in your packaging system instead.

  - there is a point of debate about generated source files, however. For example, YACC `.y` files can generate `.c` files if `yacc` is installed, and `configure.ac` can generate `configure` if autotools is installed
- `~/.config/git/ignore` should ignore any editor backup files, since these are specific to whatever editor you use but are *not* specific to the project.
- `.git/info/exclude` should ignore any one-shot things that you littered while working on a specific project. I tend to use it for temporary directories. Note however that child git repositories are always ignored anyway, whether submodules or not.

  - but as an alternative, it is *possible* to stick a `.gitignore` in a subdirectory; said `.gitignore` will ignore itself. IIRC there are some git subcommands that don't respect this though?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answers: Ignoring .dll files is the typical best way to go. Use a package manager to resolve your dependencies instead of manually adding the binaries.